# How to make Foundation menu dropdown on click rather than hover event?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation, how can I change the default drop-down on hover for the top navigation menu to bind to the click event instead?

In the JavaScript console, I can trigger the event manually, using:

```
$('.dropdown').click();
```

How can this be applied as a default override in Foundation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Top Bar can be changed to a click event by adding a simple `data-options="is_hover:false"` to the `<nav>` element. You may need to upgrade to the latest version to have access to this feature (version 4.3.2 as of September 30, 2013).

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-options="is_hover:false">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">Top Bar Title </a></h1>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Any idea how to make single menu item click-able only and keep the hover behaviour for the rest of Top Bar?